# Back4app - Swift - Cast PFObject to Class

Tags: swift, parse-platform, casting

I am trying to `cast` a `PFObject` to a `custom class` in `Swift` and I read a lot of post about it and in all of then I need to inherit my `class` from `PFObject`. The problem is that my `class` is already inherited from NSObject and there is a conflict between then.

Is there another way to cast a `PFObject` to a `custom class`?

Usuario.swift

```
class Usuario: NSObject, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Propriedades
    var nome: String?
    var foto: String?
    var dataNascimento: Date?
    var numeroTelefone: String?
    var pais: PaisCodigo?
    var telefoneE164: String?

    var objectId: String?
    var created: Date?
    var updated: Date?

    override init() {}

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        nome = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "nome") as? String
        foto = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "foto") as? String
        dataNascimento = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dataNascimento") as? Date
        numeroTelefone = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "numeroTelefone") as? String
        pais = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pais") as? PaisCodigo
        telefoneE164 = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "telefoneE164") as? String

        objectId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "objectId") as? String
        created = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "created") as? Date
        updated = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "updated") as? Date
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        if let nomeUsuario = nome {
            aCoder.encode(nomeUsuario, forKey: "nome")
        }

        if let fotoUsuario = foto {
            aCoder.encode(fotoUsuario, forKey: "foto")
        }

        if let dataNascimentoUsuario = dataNascimento {
            aCoder.encode(dataNascimentoUsuario, forKey: "dataNascimento")
        }

        if let numeroTelefoneUsuario = numeroTelefone {
            aCoder.encode(numeroTelefoneUsuario, forKey: "numeroTelefone")
        }

        if let paisUsuario = pais {
            aCoder.encode(paisUsuario, forKey: "pais")
        }

        if let telefoneE164Usuario = telefoneE164 {
            aCoder.encode(telefoneE164Usuario, forKey: "telefoneE164")
        }

        if let objectIdUsuario = objectId {
            aCoder.encode(objectIdUsuario, forKey: "objectId")
        }

        if let createdUsuario = created {
            aCoder.encode(createdUsuario, forKey: "created")
        }

        if let updatedUsuario = updated {
            aCoder.encode(updatedUsuario, forKey: "updated")
        }
    }
}
```

The Parse result using an `objectId` returns me this result:

```
<Usuario: 0x6080000abb20, objectId: 7NwpmD81w3, localId: (null)> {
    nome = "Pablo Cavalcante";
    numeroTelefone = 67992497386;
    pais = "<PaisCodigo: 0x6080000abb80, objectId: rA5wdIWEFt, localId: (null)>";
    telefoneE164 = "+5567992497386"; }
```

So it returns an `Usuario` object and I need to cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PFSubclassing`. I see that you're declaring a user class so you could just subclass `PFUser` and then write something like this:

```
class User: PFUser, PFSubclassing {

    //MARK: Propriedades
    dynamic var nome: String?
    dynamic var foto: String?
    dynamic var dataNascimento: Date?
    dynamic var numeroTelefone: String?
    dynamic var pais: PaisCodigo?
    dynamic var telefoneE164: String?
    dynamic var objectId: String?
    dynamic var created: Date?
    dynamic var updated: Date?

}
```

Of course if you're using the `init(with:)` and `encode(with:)` you have to implement it...

Comment: Ok, but I ma not going to use PFUser, I am going to use a custom class, but this custom class is already registered as NSObject and it has a conflict when used with PFObject together.

Comment: `PFObject` is already a subclass of `NSObject` so you don't have to redeclare it.

Comment: Don't I need the `NSCoding` either?

Comment: No, you can use just the code I provided. Of course, if you're using `NSCoding` for something you didn't mention then I can't advise you, but in most common situations the code I provided will suffice. If there's something new please edit the question so we can help you.